# Why do I get the PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments error when calling a Package PROC?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sys-refcursor

Here is the top part of my Package Body method:

```
PROCEDURE GetPortfolioAppsAndProjects
(
   loginId          IN VARCHAR2 := NULL,
   portfolioId      IN NUMBER := NULL,
   portfolioType    IN VARCHAR := NULL,
   ic               IN VARCHAR := NULL,
   AppIds_CUR       IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) 
IS
  INVALID_PORTFOLIO_TYPE EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
```

This runs fine when I execute from the PL/SQL execute dialogue.
I need to be able to run this from an SQL Query window though and join to other tables and what not to develop.

I'm trying to execute this sql from the Sql Window:

```
DECLARE AppIds_CUR SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   IREPORT_PORTFOLIOS.GetPortfolioAppsAndProjects('EVANSF', null, null,    null, :AppIds_CUR);
END;
```

And I get this error:

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETPORTFOLIOAPPSANDPROJECTS'
```

I count 5 incoming (including one IN OUT cursor).
In my call I pass 5 including the cursor.
How can I get the results of the cursor to the output vars window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AppIds_CUR` is declared locally in your block; you don't need to treat it as a bind variable by prepending a colon:

```
DECLARE
  AppIds_CUR SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   IREPORT_PORTFOLIOS.GetPortfolioAppsAndProjects('EVANSF', null, null, null, AppIds_CUR);
END;
```

If you run what you had as a statement in SQL Developer it would prompt you for a bind value, which isn't what you want to happen, and would treat it as a varchar not a ref cursor - hence the wrong-type error.

You'd need to loop over the cursor and display it's values manually with `dbms_output` with this approach. But you could use a bind variable if you run it as a script, by declaring the type - which would be outside the block, so you don't need the `declare`:

```
variable AppIds_CUR REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
   IREPORT_PORTFOLIOS.GetPortfolioAppsAndProjects('EVANSF', null, null, null, :AppIds_CUR);
END;
/

print AppIds_CUR
```

You can display the cursor contents with the SQL Developer `print` command.

Comment: No, my cursor is declared outside of the block. Basically all you did was change DECLARE to VARIABLE.
I tried that and still get the same error message;
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETPORTFOLIOAPPSANDPROJECTS'

Comment: @Sam - your original code has `DECLARE AppIds_CUR SYS_REFCURSOR;` which is declaring the `AppIds_CUR` as a PL/SQL variable that is local to the block. In my first version I change the reference to the variable to drop the colon. In the my second version the `variable` command is declaring the bind variable to the client, not the block, so it needs the colon. I'm confused by your comment saying the problem still exists, but the answer being accepted...